# React Meteor Tutorial can't remove this.props.post._id

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Following the tutorial here I can't delete the text. For some reason the deleteThisPost() is never fired when I click the X. The only other change I have made to the code is to replace task to post.

http://tutorial-viewer.meteor.com/tutorial/4/react

```js
// Post component - represents a single todo item
Post = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    // This component gets the post to display through a React prop.
    // We can use propTypes to indicate it is required
    post: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },

  toggleChecked() {

    Posts.update(this.props.post._id, {
      $set: {checked: ! this.props.post.checked}
    });
  },

  deleteThisPost() {
    Posts.remove(this.props.post._id);
    console.log("Deleted" + this.props.post._id);
  },

  render() {
    const postClassName = this.props.post.checked ? "checked" : "";

    return (
      <li className={postClassName}>
      <button className="delete" onclick={this.deleteThisPost}>
        &times;
        </button>

        <input type="checkbox"
        readOnly={true}
        checked={this.props.post.checked}
        onClick={this.toggleChecked} />

        <span className="text">{this.props.post.text}</span>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the only problem but "onclick" should be "onClick" in

```
<button className="delete" onclick={this.deleteThisPost}>
```

Comment: :( Long day. Thank you.